# Hadoop starter project suggestions

Tags: hadoop, cloud, mapreduce

I would love to find a few topics, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MergeSort is a fantastic/easy one to start with. You could also go with [generating word counts for all words in a file](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount). A good source of data is the [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/) library of public domain books (you could always concatenate a few of them together).

If you want something more advanced but in the same vein as word count, you could write a very simple distributed spell checker. Peter Norvig as an awesome [simple demonstration](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) of a spell checker written in Python. A good exercise would be extending this algorithm to operate on a file in a distributed fashion.

Comment: Well, I'd hesitate to evaluate any idea without a better understand of the level/expectations of the course. But I would think that a simple, easy-to-accomplish final project would be the distributed version of the spell checker. One, you could use a much larger training set if it's sorted on HDFS, and two, you could process a document at a much faster rate, since you can consider each word independently (for this naive algorithm). Lastly, it's definitely a step above word count or merge sort in both what it accomplishes and how it's implemented.

Comment: No problem! Also noticed there is Java implementations of Norvig's algorithm listed at the bottom which you can take a look at, might help you get started.

Comment: At the bottom of the page he links to implementations in different languages. The Java implementation won't work for you, though, since I doubt it's written to run in a distributed fashion. That's where your work begins :-).

Comment: Sorry, that's asking too much. It's an academic course and you need to do the work yourself. You'll learn a lot by pushing yourself to accomplish the final project (whatever you decide to do). You learn nothing by submitting other's code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few projects [here](http://lintool.github.com/Cloud9/docs/content/patterns.html)

There is a few nice and interesting examples of small hadoop projects. Everything is described very well, additionally you can find the source code and all needed theory.